# how to setup routing on Win 7 to send all data going to 10.148.xxx over ethernet and all other ranges over wi-fi?

Tags: network-adapter

I want to setup my win 7 to route everything going to the 10.148.xxx.xxx over my Lan and everything going elsewhere over my wi-fi. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Is 10.148.xxx.xxx your local network, not connected to the Wi-Fi controller?  In that case, you should let your wireless adapter with a gateway, and your Ethernet without one.

Otherwise, you'll need to play about with the routing tables.  `route print` will show you your current routing tables, and `route /?` will show you how to use it.  You'll need to either increase the priority (with a lower number) of your wireless adapter, or lower the priority (with a higher number) of your Ethernet adapter, or both.  However, you'd have to add that into a batch file to run at startup every time, as it won't persist that across reboots http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc757323(v=ws.10).aspx